# Fetch url to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, fetch-api

I got stuck with React fundamentals :/
There is code that generates table with json data inside:

```
import React from 'react'    
import { DataTable } from 'react-data-components';

function buildTable(data) {
    const tableColumns = [
        { title: 'Author', prop: 'author' },
        { title: 'Country', prop: 'country' },
        { title: 'Title', prop: 'title' },
     ];

    return (
        <DataTable
            className="container"
            keys="id"
            columns={tableColumns}
            initialData={data}
            initialPageLength={5}
         />
    );
}


let url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1sbz3lp';

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((rows) => {
        ReactDOM.render(buildTable(rows), document.getElementById('root'));
    });
```

It gets the job done in `index.js` but is it possible to render table inside React component?

```
const Home = () => (
     //renders buildTable(rows)
)

export default Home
```

Many thanks for all possible help, looking forward.

Comment: can you show us the buldTable function that you call in the fetch render?

Comment: This looks like something you could do with a class component and internal state, have you tried this? https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class

Comment: @Rodius I have updated my question. Using `react-data-components` fro table rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `buildTable()` to `Home.js` then render the Home component in `index.js`, passing `rows` as props:

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'    
import { DataTable } from 'react-data-components'

function buildTable(data) {
  const tableColumns = [
    { title: 'Author', prop: 'author' },
    { title: 'Country', prop: 'country' },
    { title: 'Title', prop: 'title' },
  ]

  return (
    <DataTable
      className="container"
      keys="id"
      columns={tableColumns}
      initialData={data}
      initialPageLength={5}
    />
  )
}

const Home = props => buildTable(props.data)

export default Home
```

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Home from './Home'

let url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1sbz3lp'

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(rows => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Home data={rows} />, document.getElementById('root'));
  })
```

**EDIT** Stateful Home component

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DataTable } from 'react-data-components'

const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1sbz3lp'

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  buildTable = (data) => {
    const tableColumns = [
      { title: 'Author', prop: 'author' },
      { title: 'Country', prop: 'country' },
      { title: 'Title', prop: 'title' },
    ]

    return (
      <DataTable
        className="container"
        keys="id"
        columns={tableColumns}
        initialData={data}
        initialPageLength={5}
      />
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((rows) => {
        this.setState({ data: rows })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.buildTable(this.state.data)}</div>
  }
} 

export default Home
```

Comment: many thanks for your response. Do you think it is possible to render table without `ReactDOM.render` because index.js is wrapped in `<BrowserRouter>` component

Comment: The easiest workaround to your problem is to just render `<BrowserRouter />` inside your Home component.

Comment: i.e. `const Home = props => <BrowserRouter>{buildTable(props.data)}</BrowserRouter>`

Comment: To make it clear I am using this example for routing : https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78  . Does your mentioned workaround will work in this case?

Comment: Yep it's pretty much the same. It's your choice whether to put `<BrowserRouter />` inside your Home component or wrap `<Home />` in the render: `ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><Home data={rows} /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))`

Comment: Yes, but index.js renders `<BrowserRouter>` -> `<App>` -> `<Main>` -> `<Switch>` -> `<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>` Will you suggested solution bypass inner components? Or should I just try to wrap all components into one line inside render?

Comment: That changes a lot of things now that you said that. In that case, you need to make `<Home />` as a stateful component then fetch the data inside. See edits.

Comment: Yes! Much obliged for help :]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the rows as a props for your Home component and then do whatever you want.

```
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((rows) => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Home data={rows} />, document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

Now you can use `this.props.data` to get the rows information, and do what you are doing inside the buildTable here in the component.

```
 import React from 'react'

 const Home = () => (
     //this.props.data will give you the rows data and do whatever you want here.
     //renders buildTable(rows)
 )

 export default Home
```